# what is the official github for ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, git, github, navigation

I am looking for a link to official ubuntu OS development on github.(answer) it has been said in the comments it's not officially hosted on github yet some fork of git on ubuntu servers? Anyways goodwork.

Comment: It would be good to clarify your answer a bit...  Do you mean an official manual for github, or the official install of git, or the official place to push git projects to?

Comment: There is no "official github for ubuntu."

Comment: okay so after trying to phrase my question to 5 words i googled ubuntu source code and found a clean short and satafying responce http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767821/how-do-i-get-the-ubuntu-source-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, there is no "official github for ubuntu". There *is* an [account of the Ubuntu project](https://github.com/ubuntu) with a small handful of repositories. But next to all Ubuntu packages are managed on Canonical's own platform, [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). By default, Launchpad uses [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) for code hosting and version control, but [Git is supported](https://help.launchpad.net/Code/Git) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a manual, try here:  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

That's where I learned git.  Very complete: has more information than you will use in your lifetime.

And once you've read through all 574 pages, if you still have questions, don't come to me, because I won't know what to say.  ;)

Comment: When I look up "ubuntu desktop x64" on github I expect to find the source code of the OS like the kernel and gui as well as a wiki to build each... even if it was just a .get with submodules.

Comment: @RexFenderBaird Your expectations are you problem ;)